# Retrieve data from a c# event

Tags: c#

I have to access data from an event in another class.
In that class things are like this:

```
namespace MavLink
{
   public class Mavlink
    {
        ...
        public event PacketReceivedEventHandler PacketReceived;
        ...
        private void ProcessPacketBytes(byte[] packetBytes, byte rxPacketSequence)
        {
            ...
            if (PacketReceived != null)
            {
                PacketReceived(this, packet);
            }
            ...
        }

    }

    public delegate void PacketReceivedEventHandler(object sender, MavlinkPacket e);
}
```

And in the main I've tried to do like this:

```
        ...
        m.ParseBytes(newlyReceived);

        m.PacketReceived += (sender, e) => {
            Console.WriteLine(e.SystemId);
            Console.WriteLine(e.ComponentId);
            Console.WriteLine(e.SequenceNumber);
            Console.WriteLine(e.TimeStamp);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        };
```

But it doesn't seem work.

Thank you for your help.

Edit:
It compiles without errore but nothing is printed on the console. I don't know how to check if the event has been rised though.

Comment: _doesn't seem to work_ doesn't give us any info. Is the event not being fired? are the `e` properties empty? Does it throw any exception?

Comment: How it doesn't work? Where do you assign variable packet?

Comment: Please elaborate on "does not work" - any compiler errors, any runtime errors, unexpected behaviour?

Comment: You didn't invoke event. (or show the part you invoke it)

Comment: Where is "ParseBytes"-Method ? You showed "ProcessPacketBytes"-Method. And where does the "packet"-variable come from ?

Comment: judging by your edit. I think the application ends up faster then event is received.

Comment: Try debugging: where should that code be called? Does your app arrive at the calling line? Where should *that* be called from? etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well on this what I read I have created a usual Event that will give you some data to access.

We start with creating the event.

```
    public delegate void PacketReceivedEventHandler(var pPacket);
    public event PacketReceivedEventHandler PacketReceived;
```

I put a var in there cause I didn't exactly saw what you are "delivering". Just change it into whatever you need.

So, lets continue. Place this when the Event needs to be triggered.

```
if (Mavlink.PacketReceived != null)
    Mavlink.PacketReceived(YourPackage);
```

*YourPackage* is whatever you want to deliver.

But you need to subscribe a event to do stuff with it.

```
Mavlink.PacketReceived += Mavlink_PacketReceived;
```

C# usually created a class if you double tab after the +=. But here is the class I created.

```
    private void Mavlink_PacketReceived(var pPacket)
    {
        if(pPacket != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pPacket.SystemId);
            Console.WriteLine(pPacket.ComponentId);
            Console.WriteLine(pPacket.SequenceNumber);
            Console.WriteLine(pPacket.TimeStamp);
            Console.WriteLine(pPacket.Message);
        }
    }
```

I dont know what comes after that in your code, but make sure that there will be something to make you command line wait so it wont close after firing that.

Comment: Ok, my mistake was to subscribe to the event after it triggered. Thank you for helping me to understand. Now it works.

Comment: @user2833876 happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I made an example, which works fine, hope it helps. Replace EventHandler by your PacketRecievedEventHandler:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sender = new Sender();
        var reciever = new Reciever(sender);
        sender.ProcessPacketBytes(null, byte.MaxValue);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

/// <summary></summary>
public class Sender
{
    private readonly object _objectLock = new object();

    public event EventHandler PacketReceived
    {
        add
        {
            lock (_objectLock)
            {
                PacketRecievedEvent += value;
            }
        }

        remove
        {
            lock (_objectLock)
            {
                PacketRecievedEvent -= value;
            }
        }
    }

    private event EventHandler PacketRecievedEvent;


    public void ProcessPacketBytes(byte[] packetBytes, byte rxPacketSequence)
    {
        EventHandler handler = this.PacketRecievedEvent;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}

public class Reciever
{
    public Reciever(Sender sendertest)
    {
        sendertest.PacketReceived += (sender, e) =>
        { Console.WriteLine(e.GetType()); };
    }
}
```

}